# Rails validate_existence_of plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm reading the book *Learning Rails* by O'Reilly and it recommends using the validate_existence_of plugin. When I run:

ruby script/plugin install http: //svn.hasmanythrough.com/public/plugins/validates_existence/

it says it's already installed, but when I use it, I get a message saying:

```
NoMethodError in AwardsController#index 
undefined method `validates_existence_of' for #<Class:0xb5fde868>
```

When I say:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  validates_existence_of :student
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the install from the correct directory (rails app top level)? Is the file validates_existence.rb somewhere in your rails app?

Comment: I'm running it from the folder where I have my application save: /home/steve/www/students

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the plugin code is installed in the vendor/plugins directory ?
Also you may need to check that the environment.rb file has the config.gem section uncommented.